# Why a have a ERROR "No current query in data reader"?

Tags: c#, mysql-connector

I have the sql command to MySql:

```cs
DB db = new DB();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
db.openConnection();
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand($"SELECT `id`, SUM(`quantity`*`price`) as sum " +
    $" FROM `orders` GROUP BY `id`",
    db.getConnection());
```

I need to get the query result like table

```
id | summ
11 | 4545
22 | 56454
etc
```

And add data into `List<Mytable>`:

```cs
class MyTable
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int sum { get; set; }
}
```

I use:

```cs
DB db = new DB();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
db.openConnection();
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand($"SELECT `id`, SUM(`quantity`*`price`) as `summ` " +
    $"FROM `orders` GROUP BY `id`", db.getConnection());

List<MyTable> result;

using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    dt.Load(reader);

    result = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(
        se => new MyTable()
        {
            id = se.Field<int>("id"),
            sum = se.Field<int>("summ") //This line has mistake, ERROR
        }).ToList();
}
```

but with only `id` - work, so
how do I fix the line so that everything works?

Comment: What are the details of the exception that you get?

Comment: Is `summ` really an `int`, or is it a float or decimal?

Comment: @Crowcoder, int

Comment: `price` is really an int? OK, what are the complete details of the exception? "No current query in data reader" doesn't seem like an error you would get on that line.